# Using Oracle's WITH clause in Java

Tags: java, oracle, with-clause

How can I execute a query with Oracles's WITH clause in Java. For e.g

```
with TEST as (
 select 1 from dual
)
select * from TEST
```

I tried but I get `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword`

Comment: Hope that is not the problem when you execute it through java, did you try executing the same in `> Oracle 9`? Try `with TEST as (select 1 as col1 from dual) select col1 from TEST`. This should work, I don't have oracle installed on my machine.

Comment: The statement should work just fine from Java. You will need to post the full Java code.

Comment: as a_horse_with_no name said, need more java code to check!

Comment: Thank you all! my original query was bit more complicated than this but later after reading your comments that it should work,i found out a parenthesis issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who mentioned that the query should work normally in JAVA.

I later found out that my query which was much more complicated with over 800 lines, was missing a parenthesis which made it look as if the select is missing.

So yes, the query works normally in JAVA